# How to show that the theta function is smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, theta-functions

I was reading on the theta function
$$
\vartheta(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 x}\qquad x>0
$$
The author claims that $\vartheta$ is smooth. Is there an easy way to show that this is indeed the case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By a fundamental result in differentiation of a series, we may differentiate term by term and show that derivatives of $\vartheta$ of all order exist.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Which result is this? I am only aware of those for power series

Comment: Consider the same series for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\operatorname{Re} z > 0$. The series converges locally uniformly, the terms are holomorphic, hence its sum is a holomorphic function on the right half-plane. Thus its restriction to $(0,+\infty)$ is smooth, even real-analytic.

Comment: That works. Thank you :-)

Comment: You also have $$\vartheta(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\vartheta\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ by the Poisson summation formula, so it is enough to show that $\vartheta$ is smooth over $(0,1]$ or $[1,+\infty)$.